# Capture QProcess (ls) to listview

Tags: android, c++, qt, qprocess, qtsystems

I need to offer a selection of mounted drives to the user for a procedure.  The fragment below will show me the the contents of the directory where drive mounts live.  How can I parse out the sd?? values (sda1,sdb1,etc) from the QString "command" and offer them to the user for choice? Listbox?  How to advice please.

```
   QProcess mount_dir;
   mount_dir.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
   cstring = adb + " -s " + daddr+port + " shell su -c ls /storage/;
   mount_dir.start(cstring);
   mount_dir.waitForFinished(-1);
   command=mount_dir.readAll();
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Yes, but via a kludge. I ls to a text file and process that. It still awaits a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems  you are reinventing the wheel. Please consider using [QStorageInfo](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtsystems/source/f0ca4494ccca6f247ac2548041503f52c64b306d:src/systeminfo/qstorageinfo.h) for this task, namely:

```
 Q_PROPERTY(QStringList allLogicalDrives READ allLogicalDrives NOTIFY logicalDriveChanged)
```

It may not be ported to Android, but this should be easy to do. There is no need to run QProcess for this, just use platform specific API with `QtAndroidExtras`.

As for the listview question, use this QML:

```
ListView {
    ...
    model: myStringListProprety
    // or: model: myClass.myStringListAccessor()
}
```

So, basically you either create a property (this is what I suggest), or make slot/invokable method in C++. If you had used QStorageInfo, you would be ready since the targetted property already exists there. Again, it may need Android specific backend tweaking, but this fiddling with the class would benefit others, too!